# SQL query to return number of users that has a post and users that dont have a post by categories

Tags: mysql

Coinsider two tables User and Posts with 1-N relation between user-posts. Is there a way I can execute a query in which I can return number of  users that a post and number of users that dont have a post
[image]

user 1 has a 3 post (increment by 1 in Count(atleast 1 post) for Design column)
user 2 has a 1 post (increment by 1 in Count(atleast 1 post) for Engineering column)
user 3 has a 1 post (increment by 1 in Count(atleast 1 post) for Design column)
user 4 has a 1 post (increment by 1 in Count(No posts) for Engineering column)
user 5 has a 1 post (increment by 1 in Count(No posts)  for Engineering column)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be solved, but the most intuitive option (to me) would be to use window functions, since each column in your desired output is rather simple to calculate on its own. Assuming that your user and post tables are named `user` and `post`:

```sql
SELECT `category`,
       `Count (At least 1 post)`,
       `users_per_category` - `Count (At least 1 post)` AS `Count (No post)`
FROM (
    SELECT `category`, COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) AS `Count (At least 1 post)`
    FROM `post` 
    JOIN `user` USING (`user_id`)
    GROUP BY `category`
) AS `withpost` JOIN (
    SELECT `category`, COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) AS `users_per_category`
    FROM `user` 
    GROUP BY `category`
) AS `totals` USING (`category`)
```

The first window function joins the user and the post tables to figure out how many users per category have made posts (you prevent multiple posts by one user from counting multiple times by using `DISTINCT`).

The second window function figures out how many users there are in each category.

The select statement that brings it together calculates out the "no post" result by looking at the difference between the number of users per category with the number of users who have made posts.